# Operator system of minimal dimension with one dimensional projections

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Consider the matrix algebra $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with H-S inner producr ($\langle a, b\rangle =tr (a^*b)$). What is the minimal dimension of any operator system $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that it always contains an one dimensional projection.

Further, if for such an $\mathcal{A} $ with dimension $m$, can we guarantee that there will be a set of mutually orthogonal projections spanning $\mathcal{A}$?

Advanced thanks for  any comments, suggestions, references, and etc..

Comment: It is not clear to me what role you expect the inner product to play. Operator systems depend on your notion of positivity; are you defining an alternative notion of positivity using the HS product?

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right. The inner product does not play any role here. It is the standard positivity which I need.